# Displaying the viewers rough location in custom google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, location

I have been working on a website using the google maps API in which I am making my own map from scratch (much like a "fantasy" world map).

What i would like is that when the user was viewing a certain area (not just centered on a single point but maybe an area that is multiple "screens" in width) the location would be displayed over the map, in a div placed over the map most likely, and this location would change as the user scrolled and entered another area.

For example, as the user scrolled over an area of desert the div would display "Desert", but as the center of the screen moved over the sea then it would display "Sea" etc.

I imagine it would involve defining "locations" that were areas between numerous Lat/Long points, and tracking the users location also.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What you want is very difficult because standard, real-world geocoding will not apply to a fantasy map. Any geocoding will need to be bespoke, and it will be hard to find an expert to help because such expertise is very limited. My immediate thought is that you might consider [jVectorMap](http://jvectormap.com/) instead of Google maps. For this particular aspect, you stand a better chance of success because jVectorMap inherently works with defined areas. On the downside, you might find jVectorMap too limited in other respects, particularly graphical detail (terrain, etc).

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, i think i will end up sticking with google maps as it works so well in all other respects. Do you by any chance have any links to info on the "geocoding" aspect of google maps, I will probably look into that to better understand the nature of what im asking, though youre right it will involve a lot of bespoke coding (if its possible at all).

Comment: Awnine, I know only of the Geocoder aspects of Google.maps that appear in the "Services" section of the [API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference), but these tell you how to *use* such services, not how to *set up* (and then access) a bespoke service of your own - and that's what you want. You will have to phrase a suitable Google search or ask another question here on SO - the title of this question will not attract the right expertise.

Comment: appreciated, i will continue research elsewhere and then try and break the problem up into smaller parts and solve them one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found an answer to the issue so i thought id post it up here for posterity in case anyone else wanted to do the same, or if anyone wanted to improve upon it.

I used the LatLngBounds object to define 2 areas on the map, like so:

```
    var desert = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
                new google.maps.LatLng(27.694746, 28.294032),
                new google.maps.LatLng(62.921001, 78.391689)
                );
            var plains = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
                new google.maps.LatLng(82.171166, 131.930577),
                new google.maps.LatLng(84.144231, 105.541417)
                );
```

and then used a function to track the screen center coordinates and detect whether they were within either of these Bounds. If so the inner HTML of a div (placed over the map) would be updated.

```
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function() {
            trackCenter = map.getCenter();
    if (desert.contains(trackCenter)) {
    var place = 'Sands of Time';
    }
    else if (plains.contains(trackCenter)) {
    var place = "Plains of Kh'rrnthar";
    }
    else {
    place = 'the Frozen Sea';
    }
    document.getElementById('locationlabel').innerHTML = '<p>Location ~ ' + place + '</p>';
            });
```

I hope this is of use to someone, regards